# CakePHP group and count

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am having trouble figuring this out.

I have the following 3 tables: -

**Transactions Table**

- ID
- Date
- List item

**Products Table**

- ID
- Name
- Price

**Products_Transactions Table**

- Transaction_ID
- Product_ID
- Quantity

So the relationship is as follows - a transaction is made, and then the products_transactions table joins them together since a transaction can have multiple products and a product can have multiple transactions. The join_table also keeps track of the amount sold, so, for instance, a newspaper sells in transaction #1 and with a quantity of 2 (so 2 newspapers sold).

Now, I want to make a MySQL statement that finds all products sold, in a specific date interval, so I get something like this: -

- 3 x Newspapers
- 12 x Sodas
- 15 x Beer

So, it just counts and sums up all the products sold.

I have seriously tried everything - I am working with CakePHP so a solution provided in that would be helpful, but even just the plain SQL to achieve this might help me out.

So far, this is what I have: -

```
$productTransactionsTable = TableRegistry::get('products_transactions');
    $productsTransactions = $productTransactionsTable->find('all');
    $productsTransactions->matching('transactions', function ($q) {
        return $q->where([
            'transaction_date >=' => new \DateTime('-1 week'),
            'transaction_date <=' => new \DateTime('now'),
            'device_id IN' => $this->deviceIdsInDepartment(2)
        ]);
    });
    $productsTransactions->contain(['products']);

    $productsTransactions->select([
        'count' => $productsTransactions->func()->count('quantity'),
        'name' => 'products.name'
    ]);

    $productsTransactions->groupBy('products.id');
```

But this just gives out 1 single result that counts everything together into 1 row, like this:

```
/src/Controller/EconomyController.php (line 665)
```

[
    (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

```
    'count' => (int) 4504,
    'name' => 'D Morgenbrød',
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'products_transactions'

}
```

]

Any help is appreciated! I am seriously stuck here!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are counting the total number of sold quantities and grouping so you are getting above results. I think, you need to try the following approach:

```
$data = $query
    ->select([
      'name' => 'products.name',
      'quantity' => 'products.quantity',
    ])
    ->group('products.id');
```

Comment: yea the problem was I that I used groupBy and not group -.-'

Comment: How to know the number of grouped records?

Comment: @rahim.nagori you can use count in the select itself.

$query->select([ 
'name, 
'AssignedCount' => $q->func()->count($this->aliasField('name'))
]
)->group('products.id');

Comment: Thank you for the response I already got this but now the problem is I have to return this count with my paginate in cakePhp. Any idea for this?

Comment: @rahim.nagori Are you setting this value in the controller? if yes, Is the value not available in "variables" tab in the debug kit? If not, Do you mind publishing your code snippet.